# How to remove decimal point from an arbitary number?

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I've a parameter which can take integer as well as fractional values. Each of these parameters correspond to a geometry which I want to save. I've something like

```
surface.save('domain_analysis_sy%.2f_%dx%dx%d.stl' % (sy, delta, Ly, Lx))
```

However, I would like to avoid having a decimal point in the name. In this particular case, I modified it like

```
surface.save('domain_analysis_sy%de-2_%dx%dx%d.stl' % (float("%.2f" % sy) * 100, delta, Ly, Lx))
```

For some other cases, accuracy is important and I cannot afford to reduce it to only 2 decimal points. Also, I want to avoid doing something like

```
surface.save('domain_analysis_sy%de-10_%dx%dx%d.stl' % (float("%.10f" % sy) * 10**10, delta, Ly, Lx))
```

because that becomes quite messy for integer cases. Is there a clean way where I can specify this parameter without a decimal point, while avoiding unnecessarily long numbers?

Comment: How about just replacing the "." if it is there with something else like "_" or even an empty string?  `str(sy).replace(".", "_")`

Comment: This is definitely a possible way. Wasn't aware of this replace function.